# Generate serializable domain model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, xml-serialization

I would like to generate domain model for my asp.net mvc 2 application. This should be based on my database and the resulting model needs to be serializable into an xml file? What would be the best way to do this? Do I have to write the domain model manually or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

[Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) is something you should look for. It can create the domain model from your existing database. You should look into the [details of EDMX file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982042.aspx) on your point where you want your resulting domain model to be in XML format.

Comment: How do I get the XML exactly?

Comment: i mean how can i persist an instance of this model to an xml file?